# Custom edit button not setting mui x-data-grid row mode to edit

Tags: next.js, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

Im fairly new to mui and am having trouble with triggering the row mode to change with a custom icon action  button like is displayed in the example in their docs for the [full featured crud table](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/editing/)

Here is the component code that is pretty close to the example from their docs. For reference i am using next.js and typescript.

```
const EditRateTable: React.FC<EditRateTableProps> = ({ compId }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<GridRowsProp[]>([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);
  const [rowModesModel, setRowModesModel] = useState<GridRowModesModel>({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(CONFIG.apiUrl, {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            query: `
              query FindRatesByCompany($compId: Int!) {
                findRatesByCompany(compId: $compId) {
                  id
                  name
                  category
                  price
                  unit
                }
              }
            `,
            variables: {
              compId: compId,
            },
          }),
        });

        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error("Error fetching data");
        }

        const responseData = await response.json();
        setData(responseData.data.findRatesByCompany);
      } catch (error) {
        setIsError(true);
      } finally {
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [compId]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(rowModesModel);
  }, [rowModesModel]);

  const handleEditClick = (id: GridRowId) => {
    setRowModesModel({ ...rowModesModel, [id]: { mode: GridRowModes.Edit } });
  };

  const handleSaveClick = (id: GridRowId) => {
    setRowModesModel({ ...rowModesModel, [id]: { mode: GridRowModes.View } });
    // Implement save logic here
  };

  const handleCancelClick = (id: GridRowId) => {
    setRowModesModel({ ...rowModesModel, [id]: { mode: GridRowModes.View } });
  };

  const processRowUpdate = (newRow: GridRowsProp) => {
    // Implement logic to update the row in your state and backend
    return newRow;
  };

  const handleRowModesModelChange = (newRowModesModel: GridRowModesModel) => {
    setRowModesModel(newRowModesModel);
  };

  if (isLoading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (isError) return <p>Error fetching data</p>;

  const columns = [
    { field: "id", headerName: "ID", flex: 0.1 },
    { field: "name", headerName: "Name", flex: 0.25 },
    { field: "category", headerName: "Category", flex: 0.25 },
    {
      field: "price",
      headerName: "Price",
      flex: 0.2,
      type: "number",
      editable: true,
    },
    { field: "unit", headerName: "Unit", flex: 0.2 },
    {
      field: "actions",
      type: "actions",
      headerName: "Actions",
      getActions: ({ id }: { id: GridRowId }) => {
        const isInEditMode = rowModesModel[id]?.mode === GridRowModes.Edit;

        if (isInEditMode) {
          return [
            <GridActionsCellItem
              icon={<Icon icon="mdi:content-save"></Icon>}
              label="Save"
              onClick={() => handleSaveClick(id)}
            />,
            <GridActionsCellItem
              icon={<Icon icon="mdi:cancel"></Icon>}
              label="Cancel"
              onClick={() => handleCancelClick(id)}
            />,
          ];
        }

        return [
          <GridActionsCellItem
            icon={<Icon icon="mdi:pencil"></Icon>}
            label="Edit"
            onClick={() => handleEditClick(id)}
          />,
        ];
      },
    },
  ];

  return (
    <Card>
      <CardHeader title="Editable" />
      <Box sx={{ height: 500 }}>
        <DataGrid
          rows={data}
          columns={columns}
          pageSize={10}
          pagination
          editMode="row"
          rowModesModel={rowModesModel}
          onRowModesModelChange={handleRowModesModelChange}
          processRowUpdate={processRowUpdate}
          onCellDoubleClick={(params) => {
            const { id } = params;
            handleEditClick(id);
          }}
        />
      </Box>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default EditRateTable;
```

after adding the onCellDoubleClick to the grid i was able to get the icon and state to change when initiating the mode change from the cell, but i am unable to have the row mode correctly change by using these action buttons like the functionality displayed in the example grid.

Im not sure if I have a fundamental misunderstanding of how the x-data-grid operates and any help would be appreciated.